# Pointer to owner class

Tags: c++, c++11

Granted a class that manages its children from its own type, with each children having a pointer back to its parent.

```
class Class {
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Class>, 4> children;
    std::weak_ptr<Class> parent;
}
```

A `weak_ptr`, like in the code above, does not work, because it has to be initialized through a shared ptr.

```
void initChild() {
    subtrees[0] = std::make_shared<Class>(std::shared_ptr<Class>(this));
}
```

This would obviously delete `this` and result in an error.

Is there any possibility to have a weak reference to the parent without using raw `pointers`, or would that be the only option?

Comment: If you don't need to reseat the parent, you could just store a reference; otherwise a private, naked pointer is fine, too -- since it's private, it's under your control and its semantics aren't going to leak. Finally, there's `std::shared_from_this`, but that's not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the parent pointer as an observable member (i.e. NOT something that must be allocated/destroyed), a raw pointer is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `shared_from_this` and really want to use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` for some reason, then you can create a factory method that constructs the Class objects, and then sets up the members (parent and children) from outside:

```
template<class... Args>
shared_ptr<Class> make_class(shared_ptr<Class> parent, size_t childIndex, Args&&... args)
{
      auto p = make_shared<Class>(forward<Args>(args)...);
      p->parent = parent;
      parent->children[childIndex] = p;
      return p;
}
```

You could of course make this method a static member function, and then make the constructor private so that users must always use the factory method.

The issue is that without `shared_from_this` in the target class a `shared_ptr` cannot find the reference count from a raw pointer to an already shared object.