# Pointer to owner

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following class structure:

```
struct owner;
struct owned;

struct owned {
    owner* my_owner;
};

struct owner {
    owned owned_object;
};
```

Class `owned` is only to be used as a member of `owner`, and for all `owner` objects `o` the following invariant shall hold:

```
o.owned_object.my_owner == &o;
```

My questions are:

1. Does this pattern have a name?
2. Are there programming practices on how to best implement the constructors of `owner`/`owned`?

For 2., my focus is on simple and elegant code rather than top-notch efficiency. For example, I'd like to use implicitly declared constructors as much as possible.

PS: This question can be seen as a follow-up to [Pointer to owner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563919/pointer-to-owner-class).

Comment: You need to define `owned` before `owner`. Your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: I have certainly seen and used this concept. Not sure if it has a name (probably has, since it seems almost every technique you could have in C++ has a name)

Comment: @juanchopanza Fixed. Although things like that make me furious every time I encounter them. In what century are we living?

Comment: @Niall Not known by Google, so not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @gTcV, as you have it here, the pattern would be a "structural" pattern. If you have more context on how it is used, you may find a  "creational" or "behavioural" pattern that contain the "pointer to owner/parent" as one of its elements. Else I would think the "pointer/reference to owner" is pretty much on the mark.

Comment: Circular dependency, and this is not a pattern. It is an anti-pattern

Comment: @BЈовић So how do I fix it?

Comment: One of ways is to fix the design. Maybe by merging those two classes

Comment: A house needs to know who lives in it, and residents need to know their house. It seems reasonable to me for a circular reference there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case shown above, there is a simple solution to the problem: In the `owner` class, introduce a pointer `copy_` and modify the copy constructor/assignment operator such that `copy_` always points to the last copy of the `owner` object. When copying `owned`, we get the address of the new object through `old_object.my_owner.copy_`.

To maximize code reuse, we introduce an `owner` base class and an `owner_ptr` class as follows.

```
class owner {
public:
    owner() = default;
    owner(const owner& to_copy) { to_copy.copy_ = this; }
    owner& operator=(const owner& to_copy) { to_copy.copy_ = this; return *this; }

private:
    mutable owner* copy_;
    template<class> friend class owner_ptr;
};

template<class Owner>
class owner_ptr {
public:
    owner_ptr(Owner* o) : owner_(o) {}
    owner_ptr(const owner_ptr& to_copy) : owner_(to_copy.owner_->copy_) {}
    owner_ptr& operator=(const owner_ptr& to_copy) { owner_ = to_copy.owner_->copy_; return *this; }

    Owner& operator*() const { return static_cast<Owner&>(*owner_); }
    Owner* operator->() const { return static_cast<Owner*>(owner_); }

private:
    owner* owner_;
};
```

Getting the desired owner/owned relationship now requires only minor changes to the original code.

```
struct some_owner;
struct some_owned;

struct some_owned {
    some_owned(some_owner* o) : my_owner(o) {}
    owner_ptr<some_owner> my_owner;
};

struct some_owner : owner {
    some_owner() : owned_object(this) {}
    some_owned owned_object;
};
```

There are some caveats with this approach though:

- All copies of the same `some_owner` object must happen sequentially, i.e. no multithreaded copies and no nested copies from the same object.
- The shown approach only works if moving the `some_owner` class involves moving the `some_owned` class. If that's not the case, e.g. when `some_owned` is stored in a vector, we must implement an old-school observer pattern for the event that the `owner` class is moved. Coding `owner` and `owner_ptr` is then a bit more work, but the resulting code is as simple to use as before and the overhead is increased only slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there is an actual name because it is not a very useful pattern in the sense that it is very limiting: the classes are now completely dependent in both directions.  The good side is, that this is a simple solution, the bad side is, that this is an example of [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency#Example_of_circular_dependencies_in_C.2B.2B), which can be seen as an anti-pattern.

If you would make an interface `IOwnedOwner` (not a useful name, but describing the current situation), let owner inherit and let owned use the interface, then you would have a **callback** system.  At least here, anyone who wants to own, just has to inherit from the interface.

Using the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), where all kind of interested parties can register for notifications from the owned object, would make this even more flexible.